# Remove except some files/directories in a script; need revision

Tags: command-line, scripts, rm, zsh

I have the same problem as this question [How to delete all the files/folders from the folder except few folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508447/how-to-delete-all-the-files-folders-from-the-folder-except-few-folders) several times.
This is the reason why I wanted to write myself a script for a command rmnot. It should take an arbitrary number of files even with wildcards if necessary and delete anything (not recursevely) in the same directory except for those files. Typical example would be:

```
rmnot *tex *bib *png
```

My script works, but since I am inexperienced and want to learn it the proper way, is there a more elegant way to do write this script?

```
#!/bin/zsh

insert="-name . -or -name .."

for i in {1..$#}; do
    insert="$insert -or -name ${(P)i}"
done

insert="\( $insert \)"

eval "find -not $insert -exec rm {} \;"
```

PS: I have to use ZSH because of the double substitution `${(P)i}` anything else would work in bash as well I think.

======Optimized Version=====

```
 #!/bin/bash

 insert="-name . -or -name .."

 for i; do
    insert="$insert -or -name $i"
 done

 insert="\( $insert \)"

 find -maxdepth 1 -not $insert -delete
```

Comment: Comments: Instead of `-name . or -name ..`, use `-mindepth 1`. You don't need double substitution. Just do `for i; do insert="$insert -or -name $i"; done`. A `for x` without an `in` loops over the script arguments.

Comment: @muru Thank you with the tip for the loop! The `-mindepth 1` option brings new problems because -or forces something to have in front. So I need to define `insert= something` nevertheless before the loop. Or I need some other lines to chop the -or in front away. But I think this would be over engineering.

Comment: I'm curious. Why are you using `eval`? Also, `find` has a `-delete` command.

Comment: I was just to happy to be able to insert options via variables ;). I changed it accordingly and added `-maxdepth 1` for more security.  Since the double substitution is not necessary anymore it is even bash compatible now I think.

Comment: To be on the safe side, I'd use an array to construct the condition list for `find`. An example: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12692155/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have one last question regarding the `-delete` option. Since`find` also searches in sub directories the safest way was to also include `-maxdepth 1`?

Comment: if you don't want to go into subdirectories, then you need `-maxdepth 1`, but if that's really the case, then you should just use terdon's solution.

Comment: Yes, but an even safer way is not to use `find` for this at all :) `find` is rarely the best tool for the job when you don't want recursion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't even need a script. If you're using bash, you can turn on `extglob` and give negative patterns:

```
$ ls
foo.avi  foo.bbl  foo.bib  foo.log  foo.png  foo.tex  foo.txt  foo.wav
$ shopt -s extglob
$ rm !(*tex|*bib|*png)
$ ls
foo.bib  foo.png  foo.tex
```

As explained in `man bash`:

```
   If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several
   extended  pattern  matching operators are recognized.  In the following
   description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated
   by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the fol‐
   lowing sub-patterns:

          ?(pattern-list)
                 Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
          *(pattern-list)
                 Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
          +(pattern-list)
                 Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
          @(pattern-list)
                 Matches one of the given patterns
          !(pattern-list)
                 Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

---

With `zsh`, the equivalent is:

```
setopt extended_glob
rm ^(*tex|*bib|*png)
```

---

If you still want to write a script for this, just concatenate the arguments you give it, but don't use wildcards (`*`), let the script add them (thanks to @Helios for suggesting a simpler version):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Iterate over the arguments
for i
do
    ## Add them to the pattern to be excluded
    pat+="*$i|"
done
## Activate extglob
shopt -s extglob
## Delete non-matching files
rm !(${pat})
```

Comment: The thing is that I do not use wildcards all the time. But I think now I got enough answers to make it properly.

Comment: and especially I see that I do not need a script: extglob is now in my .zshrc

Comment: @mcocdawc no! If you use `zsh`, you should add `setopt extended_glob` to your `~/.zshrc` and use the `rm ^(*tex|*bib|*png)` syntax as I show in my answer. `extglob` is not a zsh thing, it's bash.

Comment: it works as expected now ;)

Comment: @terdon: Impressing, I learn a lot wit this script.