# Delete all files except specified files/folders using command line?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a folder containing a lot of folders and different files with the following structures :

```
NASA
│
├── a
│   ├── doc1
│   ├── doc2
│   ├── doc3
│   ├── folder1
│   └── folder2
│
├── b
│   ├── doc1
│   ├── doc2
│   ├── doc3
│   ├── folder1
│   └── folder2
│
├── c
│   ├── doc1
│   ├── doc2
│   ├── doc3
│   ├── folder1
│   └── folder2
│
├─ x
├─ y
└─ z
```

---

I want to delete the content of the folder (`NASA/`) except specified folders and files.

For example I want to keep `a` folder, `b` folder and `x` file.

I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/q/624441/338915) 
:

```
 rm !(a/) -r NASA/
```

And (as explained in the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/555318/338915)):

```
find NASA/ -type f ! -iname "x" -delete
```

But this is not very straight forward and I have to use a bash script.

Am I missing a more easy way ? How can I do this in a single command?

Comment: I guess specifying the things you _want_ to delete is not an option, right? like `rm -r c y z`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete all the files/folders from the folder except few folders?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/508447/how-to-delete-all-the-files-folders-from-the-folder-except-few-folders)

Comment: @Wayne_Yux Indeed that is not possible, I have like 1000 files/folders with random names...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `GLOBIGNORE` to set the names that will be ignored while globbing and then use `*` to match all other files/directories:

```
GLOBIGNORE='a:b:x'; rm -r *
```

**Example:**

```
$ tree 
.
├── a
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
├── b
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
├── c
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
├── x
├── y
└── z

/NASA$ GLOBIGNORE='a:b:x'

/NASA$ rm -r *

/NASA$ tree 
.
├── a
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
├── b
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
└── x
```

---

Alternately, you can use `find`, from the `NASA` directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.' ! -regex '.*/\(a\|b\|x\)$' -exec rm -r {} +
```

**Example:**

```
/NASA$ tree 
.
├── a
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
├── b
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
├── c
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
├── x
├── y
└── z


/NASA$ find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.' ! -regex '.*/\(a\|b\|x\)$' -exec rm -r {} +


/NASA$ tree 
.
├── a
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
├── b
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
└── x
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use the extended globbing, but the exclamation mark goes **before** the pattern:

```
rm -rf NASA/!(a|b|x)
```

If `extglob` is not on, activate it first:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: This worked for me.